# Implementing external formula

Tags: java, string, integer, formula

given a file with input:

```
Formula: m = (y - c) / x
Formula: m = y + c^2
```

**I want to implement each formula in java to solve for m** so that in this case I will end up with 2 answers. I have to do this as coding for each formula individually will be too time consuming for all the formulae I require.

So far my code below just detects and isolates each formula. I have also removed user input for the purposes of this question.

```
int y = 8;
int c = 2;
int x = 2;

    try{
       FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("Filename");

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;

        while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            if(strLine.startsWith("Formula")){
                String standAloneFormula = strLine.replace("Formula: ", "");
                System.out.println(standAloneFormula);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print(e);
```

The main problem that I am having is accessing the code and then applying the integer values to the string values. What would be the easiest way to solve for, in this case, **m**?

Any ideas, links or relevant code will be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Is `c^2` an XOR operation or an exponential operation?

Comment: you have variables x and y, but only a single equation that involves x and y ...

Comment: y is common in both equation 1 and 2. the only instance of x is in equation 1

Comment: Just something what popped in my mind : You can store variables and their actual values in the `HashMap<String, Integer>`. Then when you will traverse each formula you will just have to distinguish between operator and variable. If it is a variable you can assign the value by retrieving it from `HashMap`. i.e. `variableValues.get("x");` Dunno if this fits as answer so I'm putting it in comments.

Comment: Tried something like this earlier. But will try it again. Thanks

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a simple object model for equations using the [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). You can break every input line down to being a single expression possibly containing other expressions as operands. Then you can define a method `calculate(HashMap<String, Integer> values)` in all of your classes, where `values` is just the definition of all the variables that might occur in your calculation. By calling the method recursively you should in the end get the result.

You will need one class for each mathematical operation you wish to support, e.g. Addition, Subtraction, Negation, ...

Parsing the string and constructing the object hierarchy is the most difficult task actually. Would be a lot easier with a [polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) or something more easy to parse.

Overall it might be adviseable to use a tool more suited to solving mathematical problems rather than trying to code something yourself. Maybe even Excel might help.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Have started doing this, but there is a problem that I am unable solve at the moment. I have split up the formula into m, =, (, y, etc. but I need to compare for example the y in my array to my y integer. Do you know if it is at all possible to compare an integer name to an array value. Once I've done this I can worry about the mathematical operations and hierachy.

Comment: Well...a variable is just an expression. So you should have a class `Variable`, whose only field ist the name of the variable represented by the object. The `calculate(HashMap<String, Integer>)` method in there should lookup this name in the given HashMap via `containsKey(String)` and then just return the found value. If no value is found, you can just throw an exception as you will never be able to calculate anything.